# Check button click from inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm building a pure javascript alertbox script but i'm stuck at the point where the user clicks the button. What I'm trying to do is making a function that returns true or false depending on the button click. I want to do this with one single Javascript page that generates the HTML and CSS. I only know a way of returning a value from a function if you don't start a new function. The point is that i need a second function to capture the button click.

I hope you know a way to make the function return a value depending on the buttons clicked.
My Javascript code is below:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkkNijboer/BW463/)

```
function SimpleAlert( title, text, cancel)
{
    var stylesheet = document.createElement('style');
    stylesheet.id="SimpleAlertStylesheet";
    stylesheet.innerHTML="#SimpleAlertOverlay { top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; position:fixed; background:rgba(230,230,230,0.5); height:100%; width:100%; font-family:Sans-serif; } #SimpleAlertLightbox { background:#f5f5f5; border-radius:3px; width:400px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); } .SimpleAlertTopbar { background:#e5e5e5; height:24px; color:#444; line-height:24px; padding:0px 5px; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; border-bottom:1px solid #DDD } .SimpleAlertCross1 { margin:5px 15px 0px 0px; opacity:0.7; } .SimpleAlertCross2 { margin:5px 15px 0px 0px; opacity:0.5; } .SimpleAlertCross1:hover { opacity:1; } .SimpleAlertTopbar > div { float:left } .SimpleAlertMessagediv { padding:20px 40px; font-size:14px; color:#444; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv { height:26px; line-height:26px; padding:0px 40px 18px 40px; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv button { height:26px; background:#f9f9f9; border:1px solid #CCC; color:#444; float:right; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv button:hover { border:1px solid #AAA; } .SimpleAlertButtondiv button:focus { outline:none; }";

    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.id = 'SimpleAlertOverlay';
    var lightbox = document.createElement('div');
    lightbox.id = 'SimpleAlertLightbox';
    overlay.appendChild(lightbox);
    var topbar = document.createElement('div');
    topbar.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertTopbar");
    lightbox.appendChild(topbar);
    var crossdiv = document.createElement('div');
    topbar.appendChild(crossdiv);
    var crossspan = document.createElement('span');
    crossdiv.appendChild(crossspan);
    var cross = document.createElement('img');

    if(cancel)
    {
        cross.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertCross1");
    }
    else
    {
        cross.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertCross2");
    }

    cross.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
    crossspan.appendChild(cross);
    var titlediv = document.createElement('div');
    titlediv.innerHTML = title;
    topbar.appendChild(titlediv);
    var messagediv = document.createElement('div');
    messagediv.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertMessagediv");
    messagediv.innerHTML = text;
    lightbox.appendChild(messagediv);
    var buttondiv = document.createElement('div');
    buttondiv.setAttribute("class", "SimpleAlertButtondiv");
    lightbox.appendChild(buttondiv);
    var okbutton = document.createElement('button');
    okbutton.innerHTML="OK";
    buttondiv.appendChild(okbutton);
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
    document.body.appendChild(stylesheet);

    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    }

    function CenterDiv(elementId){
         var main = document.getElementById(elementId);
         var wi=main.offsetWidth;
         var he=main.offsetHeight;
         var marginleft = wi / 2;
         var margintop = he / 2;
         main.style.marginLeft="-" + marginleft;
         main.style.marginTop="-" + margintop;
         main.style.position="absolute";
         main.style.left="50%";
         main.style.top="50%"
        }
        CenterDiv('SimpleAlertLightbox');

        if(cancel)
        {
            var cancelbutton = document.createElement('button');
            cancelbutton.innerHTML="Cancel";
            cancelbutton.style.marginRight="30px";
            buttondiv.appendChild(cancelbutton);
            cancelbutton.addEventListener('click', SimpleAlertCancel , false);
        }
        cross.addEventListener('click', SimpleAlertCancel , false);
        okbutton.addEventListener('click', SimpleAlertOK , false);

        function SimpleAlertCancel()
        {
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertOverlay'));
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertStylesheet'));
            alert('Cancel');
        }
        function SimpleAlertOK()
        {
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertOverlay'));
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertStylesheet'));
            alert('OK');
        }
}
```

If something is unclear please ask me in the comments.

**To Laoujin**

My goal is to call the function and receive true or false:

```
if(SimpleAlert( title, text, cancel))
{
    //user clicked OK
}
else
{
    //user clicked Cancel
}
```

The posted answer opened new chances but maybe you already know the missing part of my code?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you need a callback after the user clicks Ok/Cancel?

Comment: @Laoujin The problem is that I want my main function, in this case SimpleAlert(), to return a value. It has to return true if the user clicks OK and it has to return false if the user clicks Cancel or the cross in the upperleft corner. But i can't get the callback from the buttons while running the main function. I don't know how can return a value from the main function if the user clicks on a generated button.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't: `SimpleAlert` returns after showing the Alert box but you only know which button the user clicks on much later. I think that a callback would solve your problem - albeit in a different way.

Comment: Why not add events to your elements?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of using a callback:

Provide an extra parameter to SimpleAlert:

`<button onclick="SimpleAlert('My title', 'The message', true, handleResult)">Start</button>`

The handleResult function:

```
function handleResult(buttonClicked) {
    if (buttonClicked) {
        alert("Ok");
    } else {
        alert("Cancel");
    }
}
```

The changed Ok/Cancel handlers:

```
 function SimpleAlertCancel()
 {
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertOverlay'));
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertStylesheet'));
        callback(false);
 }
 function SimpleAlertOK()
 {
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertOverlay'));
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('SimpleAlertStylesheet'));
        callback(true);
 }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BW463/1/)

As mentioned in the comments, code like:

```
if(SimpleAlert( title, text, cancel))
{
    //user clicked OK
}
else
{
    //user clicked Cancel
}
```

is not possible because the `SimpleAlert` cannot return a value before the user actually pressed one of the buttons. (actually it would be possible by using `setInterval` but this is not a recommendable approach!)

You can achieve the same though:

```
SimpleAlert(title, text, cancel, function(clickedOk) {
    if (clickedOk) {
        //user clicked OK
    } else {
        //user clicked Cancel
    }
});
```

Something completely different: placing the angle brackets on new lines is not really good practice in JavaScript as it can lead to [undesired behavior](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/).

Comment: Please take a look at the bottom of my question. Thanks for your answer btw!